# Bootstrap javascript works in test by not in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am following Michael Hartl's rails tutorial

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#code:bootstrap_js

And one section involves using bootstrap's javascript within the application. When I run the application using 'rails s' on example.com:3000 it works. But when I run it with passenger on example.com it does not work.

Is there something I have to do or change in the config files to make it work in production too? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess you should add your application.js like this: (config/production.rb:)

```
# config.assets.precompile += %w( application.js )
```

and in production run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Edit: or easily you can convert the .js format to .js.coffee 
further conf. options you can find here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html